# PHP Fatal Error on a native php function. Why?

Tags: php, memory, garbage-collection, fatal-error

**(Update)**
*Problem was due to my php version not being the minimum version specified in the* [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gc-collect-cycles.php).

---

**The situation:**
Getting a fatal error on a native php function. (*Using php version 5.2.17*) Any obvious reasons why?

**Error Output:**
PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function gc_collect_cycles() in /home/oursite/public_html/pdfgenerator/memory.php on line 4

**Script Contents:**

```
// memory.php
<?php

gc_collect_cycles();

?>
```

Comment: Try reading the documentation for the function, it normally has the answer to this kind of questions.

Comment: I do not understand why people do not use the documentation. It makes me physically upset to think of how many millions of man-hours could be saved by writing "php gc_collect_cycles" into Google and clicking on the first result. \*sigh\* What on earth is wrong with people.

Comment: Oops! Sorry guys. Yes version problem. And to the man who got physically upset. Maybe try taking some deep breaths? Coz it really ain't that serious! lolol

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`gc_collect_cycles()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gc-collect-cycles.php) is in PHP starting with version 5.3.0, so at 5.2.17 you won't be able to use it.

Comment: Thanks. Right -- check the version. duh.

Answer (score 6):

You've answered your own question.  This function is only available in [PHP 5.3 and up](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gc-collect-cycles.php).  You're using PHP 5.2.17

Answer (score 2):

From the manual:

> gc_collect_cycles
>
> (PHP 5 >= 5.3.0)
>
> gc_collect_cycles — Forces collection of any existing garbage cycles

So it's not available on 5.2.17